# How to download a CSV file with selenium while bypassing the file dialog

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver, linux-mint, geckodriver

I have been trying to access a url with a CSV file to download it in a specific directory, using the Selenium Webdriver for Firefox(geckodriver), in a NodeJS enviroment on Linux-Mint.

This is my code:

```js
const {Builder} = require('selenium-webdriver');
const firefox = require('selenium-webdriver/firefox');
const path = require('path');

const options = new firefox.Options();

options.setPreference('browser.download.dir', path.resolve(__dirname));
options.setPreference('browser.download.folderList', 2);
options.setPreference('browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk', 'application/x-csv');

function example(){
  let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('firefox').setFirefoxOptions(options).build();
  driver.get('http://insight.dev.schoolwires.com/HelpAssets/C2Assets/C2Files/C2ImportCalEventSample.csv');
}

example();
```

As you can see, I am correctly setting the browser option to `browser.helperApps.neverAsk.saveToDisk`, so as to be able to bypass the dialog. However, I am still getting the dialog no matter what I do. I haven't tried this code on Windows, but for my purposes it needs to work on Linux.

Am I missing something? Some preference that needs to be added or changed? Or does this not work on my current enviroment?

Thank you in advance for any help provided.

Answer (score 0):

If you are just downloading a file from link why do you need selenium?

A much simple approach will be just to get the file by http and save to file.

```
const http = require('http');
const fs = require('fs');

const file = fs.createWriteStream("C2ImportCalEventSample.csv");
const request = http.get("http://insight.dev.schoolwires.com/HelpAssets/C2Assets/C2Files/C2ImportCalEventSample.csv", function(response) {
  response.pipe(file);
});
```

If you have to use selenium let me know in the comments and i will try to find a solution for your problem using selenium.